# TFF trainer.next is not callable

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I try to run the tff example code.
This is the example code link in tff website https://tensorflow.google.cn/federated?authuser=0

But i get some problem, bug as follows

```
Unexpected keyword argument 'dummy_batch' in function call
No value for argument 'input_spec' in function call
trainer.next is not callable
```

When i following the tutorials to learn,it's on the right way until i meet

```
state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data)
```

It's the same problem next is not callable.

Please help me ,thank you very much!!!

Comment: Please expand on the details to make your issue fully reproducible. In the meantime, the issue may be caused by using an old version of TFF.

Comment: thank you very much. I had solve the problem. Dummy_batch is the old version of parameter in ' tff.learning.from_keras_model '.

Comment: And because my environment is not complete , that's reduce the problem of  'next is not callable'.I ran the code in google colab without errors.